# Is it safe to convert rca to xlr

Tags: speakers, amplifier, cable, conversion, connector

I have a pre-amplifier of which the outputs are RCA. Now i want to buy new active speakers but those only have 3pin-XLR input. is it safe for both my amplifier and active speakers just to use a simple rca to xlr converter plug?

If more information is needed let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the preamp outputs are line level, then yes it is perfectly safe to do this.

You will wire the connection up as follows:

- Ground (RCA) to Pin 1 and 3 (XLR)
- Signal (RCA) to Pin 2 (XLR)

A converter plug should be fine and it should have the same wiring as this.